# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in condition

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

This is my code to build a password confirmation, but all I got is an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in `line 3`

```
function validatePasswordConfirmation(inputName, input) {

  var password_confirmation = document.querySelector('#password-confirmation').value;

  if password_confirmation == document.querySelector('#password').value || !isEmpty(input.value) {

    showOrHideErrorMessage(inputName, true, 'invalid');
  }
  else{
    showOrHideErrorMessage(inputName, false, 'invalid');
  }

}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: `if` need parenthesis.

Comment: This question is too basic, you cam find your error on the documentation. Please search before posting a question.

Comment: used to use python. If you don't want to answer a basic question, don't click on it, simple like this. Some people just are trying to learn new languages with different documentations and make mistakes like that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error, you are missing the parentheses around your `if` condition:

```
if password_confirmation == document.querySelector('#password').value || !isEmpty(input.value) {
```

... should be:

```
if (password_confirmation == document.querySelector('#password').value || !isEmpty(input.value)) {
```

Specifically, the error you are receiving: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is telling you that the parser found an *identifier* (`password_confirmation`) where it expected to find an *open parenthesis*.

If you are just learning JavaScript, I recommend integrating a code linter of some sort into your development tool (like jslint or eslint). These kinds of issues are easily found when using tools like these.

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis on the `if` statement.

Change :

```
if password_confirmation == document.querySelector('#password').value || !isEmpty(input.value)
```

To :

```
if (password_confirmation == document.querySelector('#password').value || !isEmpty(input.value))
```